# Google Chrome-stable no hardware acceleration after 109

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, google-chrome, chromium, hardware-acceleration

I'm having an issue where google-chrome-stable does not have functioning hardware acceleration for video after version 109. This is just a chrome issue. I use chrome for password and bookmark sharing across 4 OSes

I'm using a i5-12400. Using the CPU for graphics as well. Graphics drivers are installed
Running Kubuntu 22.04

```
htpc@htpc:~$ vainfo 
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: User environment variable requested driver 'iHD'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.14 (libva 2.12.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 22.3.1 ()
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointStats
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointFEI
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointFEI
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointFEI
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointFEI
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile1            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile1            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileVP9Profile3            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile3            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain12             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain12             : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain422_10         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain422_10         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain422_12         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain422_12         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain444            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain444            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_10         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_10         : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCMain444_12         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain            : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain10          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain10          : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444         : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileAV1Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444_10      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCSccMain444_10      : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
```

Chrome 109 "chrome://gpu" output
Launched with `google-chrome-stable --use-gl=egl --disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --disable-gpu-driver-workarounds --enable-zero-copy --disable-features=UseChromeOSDirectVideoDecoder --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder,VaapiIgnoreDriverChecks,PlatformHEVCDecoderSupport,Vulkan,DefaultANGLEVulkan,VulkanFromANGLE`
[image: Chrome 109 works]

I install chrome 114, and it does not report anything under video decoding.
This screenshot is with the same (working) flags as 109.

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --use-gl=egl --disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --disable-gpu-driver-workarounds --enable-zero-copy --disable-features=UseChromeOSDirectVideoDecoder --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder,VaapiIgnoreDriverChecks,PlatformHEVCDecoderSupport,Vulkan,DefaultANGLEVulkan,VulkanFromANGLE
```

[image: Chrome 114 with same flags as 109]

I've tried the following flags, and all of them show output like below

```
google-chrome-stable --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder,Vaapi --disable-features=UseChromeOSDirectVideoDecoder
google-chrome-stable --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder
google-chrome-stable --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder,Vaapi
google-chrome-stable --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder,Vaapi --disable-features=UseChromeOSDirectVideoDecoder --disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds
google-chrome-stable --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder,Vaapi --disable-features=UseChromeOSDirectVideoDecoder --disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --disable-gpu-driver-workarounds
google-chrome-stable --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder,Vaapi --disable-features=UseChromeOSDirectVideoDecoder --disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --disable-gpu-driver-workarounds --use-gl=angle
google-chrome-stable --enable-features=VaapiVideoDecoder,Vaapi --disable-features=UseChromeOSDirectVideoDecoder --disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --disable-gpu-driver-workarounds --use-gl=egl
```

[image: Header of all flags that try to enable vaapi]

[image: Blank video hardware acceleration]

If I play any higher resolution videos, my CPU usage goes up to 400-500% in chrome and GPU usage is low. Clearly not hardware accelerated.

If I install the chromium hwacc snap version, I get everything working out of the box, with more codecs than 109 supported, but I can't really use it because all my passwords and bookmarks are not saved and cannot be synced with my google account.
[image: Chromium hwacc snap works out of the box]

How can I get chrome hardware acceleration back? This is clearly a chrome specific issue.